# Apollo React: How to refetch query when a different option is selected from select dropdown?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I need to show different data based on the selected option from the dropdown. I'm querying the value using `Query` component and that value is different for each option.
Here's the sample code for it.

```
 <Query query={CURRENT_USER}>
     {({loading, error, data}) => {
         if (loading) 
             return "loading...";
         if (error) 
             return `Error! ${error.message}`;
         return  <h1>{data.month === Date().slice(4,7).toLowerCase() ? data.amount : 0}</h1>
      }}
 </Query>
 <div>
     <select defaultValue={Date().slice(4,7).toLowerCase()}>
         <option value="jan">JAN</option>
         <option value="feb">FEB</option>
         <option value="mar">MAR</option>
         <option value="apr">APR</option>
         <option value="jun">JUN</option>
         <option value="jul">JUL</option>
         <option value="aug">AUG</option>
         <option value="sep">SEPT</option>
         <option value="oct">OCT</option>
         <option value="nov">NOV</option>
         <option value="dec">DEC</option>
     </select>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The Query component returns `refetch` which can be passed to the `onChange` function in your form. It accepts variables just like the original query.

It would look something like this:

```
<Query query={CURRENT_USER} variables={{month: this.state.month}}>
  {({loading, error, data, refetch}) => {
    if (loading) return 'loading...'
    if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`
      return (
       <h1>
         {data.month ===
           Date().slice(4, 7).toLowerCase()
             ? data.amount
             : 0
         }
       </h1>
     )
   }}
 </Query>
 <div>
   <select 
     value={this.state.month}
     onChange={(event) => refetch({variables: {month: event.target.value}}
   >
     <option value="jan">JAN</option>
     <option value="feb">FEB</option>
     <option value="mar">MAR</option>
     <option value="apr">APR</option>
     <option value="jun">JUN</option>
     <option value="jul">JUL</option>
     <option value="aug">AUG</option>
     <option value="sep">SEPT</option>
     <option value="oct">OCT</option>
     <option value="nov">NOV</option>
     <option value="dec">DEC</option>
   </select>
 </div>
```

Comment: I'm curious, does Query really do refetch on variable change? I didn't find such information in Apollo docs. I thought that for such cases it has special refetch() function. It's cool if it does.

Comment: @AndreyMedvedev Thanks for pointing that out. `Query` returns `refetch` which can be used pretty easily. I updated my answer.

Comment: `refetch` is defined in the `Query`, it'll throw an error on using it in `select` tag that is outside the `Query` and ofcourse moving the entire `select` into the `Query` is obviously a solution to that but is there anyway I can cause `refetch` from outside `Query` and most importantly query `CURRENT_USER` doesnt take any variables.

Answer (score 2):

Although you can, it's not necessary to use `refetch` for this typical use case. You can simply do a normal `setState`. Apollo will see the variables changed and refetch the query automatically. You would typically use refetch if you have a nested component needing changes, and you aren't drilling down an onChange handler that is calling setState (and other reasons).

To point out also, you would need to call setState in the onChange handler, so the select dropdown would update. So, even if you added refetch to the below, the Query would fetch a second time unnecessarily.

```
<Query query={CURRENT_USER} variables={{ month: this.state.month }}>
  <select
    value={this.state.month}
    onChange={event => this.setState({ month: event.target.value })}
  >
```

Comment: It is not causing `refetch` onChange!

Comment: Can you please add the code for your entire component, instead of just the render method?